# Code hunt game 02.05

Tags: java

Idea is to make the most *elegant* code as you can. Theme of section: loops.
Task: return sum of squares of numbers from 1 to (n-1)
example: 6 -> 55 (which is 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2)

I chose Java as language and wrote this code:

```
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int n) {
        int r=0;
        for(--n;n>=0;r+=n*n--);
        return r;
    }
}
```

but compiler says that my code is not *elegant* enough. Can you help?
Link:[CodeHunt](https://www.codehunt.com/)

Comment: This belongs in code golf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you paste the actual message your compiler gives you saying it is not elegant?

Comment: It doesn't say a word about it, but it measures results in blocks of "skills". For 3 blocks it sais that code is elegant, but no matter what I do - I always get only 2 blocks

Comment: You don't need loop. It's very inefficient. The sum of first n squares is a well-known series. Try:
`public class Program { public static int Puzzle(int n) { int x = n -1; return x*(x+1)*(2*x+1)/6; } }`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site: possibly codegolf or codereview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need loop that series. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

```
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int n) {
    int x = n -1;
    //sum of first n-1 squares
    return x*(x+1)*(2*x+1)/6;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several very inelegant aspects:

- *Inline increments/decrements*: they make the code very confusing, because most people are no experts in when the variable will actually decrement, what will for instance happen with `m = (n--)*(--n);` (the answer is `m = n*(n-2); n -= 2;`). For some small simple expressions inline decrements make code more readible. But in nearly all cases, there is no performance gain, as the compiler is smart enough to convert a readible code to one with inline increment/decrement itself.
- *loops with no body*: most people simply get confused, think the next instruction is part of the body, etc. Most IDEs even advice to always use braces and write something in the body.
- *manipulation of a parameters*: this is confusing and makes code less extensible. Say you want to extend your code with some part below and you perform *copy-past*, since the parameters don't have their original value, the pasted code will work differently. IDEs mostly advice to make at least a copy. Nearly every compiler can optimize this if it turns out the parameters is not used any further.
- *decrement in for loop*: although this sometimes yields a small improvement in code performance, most programmers are used to for loops that increment.
- *semantical variable names* (something a compiler cannot detect): it is recommended that you name your variables appropriately, use `sum` instead of `r`. The java compiler sees names simply as identifiers. So at runtime there is no difference, it is however more readable for other people and yourself when you revisit your code months later.

These are all very bad ways to write an algorithm. Most books strongly suggest that unless you really need to write a code that takes the absolute maximum out of your CPU, you better write nice, well structured and readable code. And furthermore if that is the case, there are more efficient languages than Java.

---

As a better version, I recommend the following code:

```
public class Program {

    public static int Puzzle(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            sum += i*i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

---

Furthermore you don't need a `for`-loop to calculate this (as pointed out [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20i%5E2%20with%20i%20from%201%20to%20n-1)):

```
public class Program {

    public static int Puzzle(int n) {
        return n*(n-1)*(2*n-1)/6;
    }

}
```

Comment: Still,it said that it's not good enough. I think it wants something small and obvious like
    return Array.Sum(0,n)
But I don't know if there exists such an operation

Comment: As @morrizon states, you don't need a for loop at all, you can simply use sum unrolling: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20i^2%20with%20i%20from%201%20to%20n

Answer (score 1):

Elegance may be a combination of simplicity and accuracy.  The biggest issue with your method is that it isn't simple; it may produce the correct result, but it's needlessly complicated with unusual iteration and the fact that you're running a for-loop for its side effects.

Why not go with the more direct approach instead?

```
public static Puzzle(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(i, 2);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I would replace `Math.pow(n, 2)` with `n*n` since `n` is an integer and for small powers, the unrolled version is more readable. Furthermore since `n` is an integer, it will be more efficient (otherwise `2` must always be interpreted first, etc.).

Comment: Furthermore you should sum up with `i*i` and not `n*n`.